# How to execute git-bash command with system() or shell() in R

Tags: r, git-bash

I would like to run some command in `git-bash` shell via `system()` or `shell()` functions in R. I am on windows and the default shell is the command prompt. Is there any way I can switch the shell in `system()` to `git-bash`?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm on windows with git-bash, and `system('"/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/ls.exe"')` works without needing to change anything to specifically use git-bash. Perhaps you need to update your `PATH` env-var? What are you trying that is not working?

Comment: My git credentials work fine in git-bash when using the terminal tab in RStudio (git-bash is my default shell in the Terminal tab). However, when I try `git clone git@github.com:someuser/somefolder` in `system()` it does not recognize my credentials. I understand I can set my credentials in command prompt too but I would like to not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `%PATH%` includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\`, you should be able to system call:

```
bash --login -i -c "your command"
```

The [OP JdeMello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199514/jdemello) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069587/how-to-execute-git-bash-command-with-system-or-shell-in-r/56070847?noredirect=1#comment98794972_56070847):

> Yup: Didn't have `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` in `PATH`.
>
> For completion, we can add `Git\bin` to PATH in `R` (if necessary):
>
> ```
> if(length(grep("(?i)Git//bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"))) == 0) 
>     Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"),";C://Program Files//Git//bin"))
> ```
>
> That worked for me.

Comment: Yup. Didn't have `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` in `PATH`. For completion, we can add `Git\bin` to `PATH` in `R`  (if necessary): `if(length(grep("(?i)Git//bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"))) == 0) Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"),";C://Program Files//Git//bin")) `. That worked for me. Thanks @VonC !

Comment: @JdeMello Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.